# Codename One how to communicate with other users of an app

Tags: communication, codenameone

I am developing an app that requires communication between other users of the same app.  A user might want to invite another user to an event, so the request must be sent directly to a specific user with the event data.  If the invitee accepts the invite, the inviter will need to receive a message back to notify and record the acceptance.  How would I go about achieving this communication functionality?  What are the main pieces to this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you would with any platform, using the network.

The question is how do users discover each other? Vicinity? Common interests?

Either way you will need to create a server to which the apps connect via a web service with the proper information (e.g. location, common interests etc.) then the server can return the identifier for the appropriate match and facilitate communication between them.

Comment: Thank you Shai.  I appreciate how you are always willing to help.  I was hoping that there was a more direct solution so I could bypass client/server paradigm.